# Set values when the input is not in a form using rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm new in web scraping. I'm trying to search a page using the rvest package in R.
Normally it would be extracting the form from the page, then set values in the input and submit.

Normally if you execute this :

```
library(rvest)
url <- "www.google.com"
url %>% read_html() %>% html_form()
```

It would retrun the form :

```
[[1]]
<form> 'f' (GET /search)
 <input hidden> 'ie': ISO-8859-1
 <input hidden> 'hl': fr
 <input hidden> 'source': hp
 <input hidden> 'biw': 
 <input hidden> 'bih': 
 <input text> 'q': 
 <input submit> 'btnG': Recherche Google
 <input submit> 'btnI': J'ai de la chance
 <input hidden> 'gbv': 1
```

The problem I have with the web page i'm working with is that the input is not in a form :

```
library(rvest)
url <- "http://www.seloger.com/"
url %>% read_html() %>% html_form() #newsletter form only
url %>% read_html() %>% html_node("input") # i get my input
```

So the input is in  not in 
What can i do? And how can i submit for the search?

Thank you.